# which wpf control should I use in case i need only 2 columns?

Tags: wpf, user-interface, user-controls, wpf-controls

which wpf control Should i use in case I need only two columns. the first colum contains Property name and second column contains its value. however, on the top of all those properties I need a header of each columns like PROPERTY and VALUE. I know datagrid would not be a good solution for this. can someone suggest me which control to use or should I stick to Grid and set those header manually.

Comment: GridView, DataGrid, ListBox with a Grid as ItemsTemplate and two columns in ColumnDefintion. Whatever your heart desires.

Comment: I'm curious as to the reason you don't like DataGrid for this one?

Comment: because I need to pop the properties for a selected item in tree.these properties are same for all items in a tree however contain different value.

Answer (score 0):

If you really can't use a `DataGrid`, then the `GridView` is probably your best bet... and when I say best, I mean easiest really. Assuming that you have a collection of your data type named `Items` and that the data type inside the collection has two properties, `Property` and `Value`, you could use this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Property" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Property}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Value" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Value}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```